# Upwork taking 20% of my money. Alternatives

Tags: freelance-websites

I am not very happy with Upwork now taking 20% of what I make.  I have had to raise my price just to continue getting 10%.

Does anybody have any suggestions for a good alternative for Upwork?  I do use Guru.com but it only has a new job every hour, compared to a hundred jobs per hour.  I do have established customers paying me via Paypal, but new customers want to stick with the platform.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you freelancing in IT ? You might want to checkout Toptal

Comment: If I am right, UpWork will charge you 20% for the first 500€ then revert to 10%.

Comment: I am freelancing IT.  I am just getting started and only have 5-10 hours that I can dedicate per project.  Usually my projects are less than $500.  So the 20% hurts.

Comment: You're looking at things wrong... you're focusing on the 20% in fees rather than the 80% you've earned. Change your mindset. There will almost always be fees somewhere... 4% for PayPal, merchant fees, domain registration, hosting, etc. It is important to focus on what you are earning, not on the fees you must pay to earn *anything*.

Comment: The fee doesn't hurt if you include it in your price calculation. If you want to get 300$ for a job, then you have to demand 375$.

Comment: I do agree that a site charging a 20% comission is outrageous.

Comment: Thank Jean.  Toptal looks fantastic, but I don't think my skills are good enough.  Thanks Scott.  I haven't left Upwork immediately because I do enjoy the 80%.  But just because "enjoy" my house, doesn't mean I should "enjoy" with the 30 year mortgage.  If I can find a way out I should.  Thanks for the pep talk though. :-)   I did raise my price Apfelsaft, but the customers are paying more just to cover Upwork's charge.  Not my fault, but still, nobody is getting a good deal out of that except Upwork.

Comment: I would venture to say you are not doing your math; upwork is taking *more than 20%*. The commission is calculated in the gross value as far as I remember. It is worse than having a boss, having none of the perks of it. I would like to find alternatives to sysadmin work too actually, because as it is , I wont use upwork. And the prices are ridiculous that "customers" are willing to pay.

Comment: 20% for the first $500 is nothing considering the benefits you get, most important the fact you are guaranteed to be paid, given you follow their guidelines.

Comment: Well, if the project is big enough, it will take only 10%.

Comment: So you saw 20% fee, and did not see 5% one. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agreed! Upwork charges a hell of a lot of the Fee. On the top of that Freelancer had to pay withdrawal fees, currency conversion fee, bank fee, etc. and the actual amount which a freelancer receives is very small. So, strategy is to deliver good work, make your clients happy and take them out of Upwork with mutual agreement. Upwork charges a Payment Processing fee to clients as well, which can be a plus point for you to convince them.

Other alternatives can be:
http://www.guru.com/
https://www.toptal.com/
https://outsource.com/
https://freelancer.com/

Comment: It's actually against Upwork TOS to skip Upwork as a payment gateway (look up Upwork TOS Non Circumvention Clause)

Comment: When I use Upwork, I don't have to pay withdrawal fees, currency conversion fees, or bank fees. Maybe you should change your withdrawal method.

Comment: You can take a client out of Upwork. But you have to pay Upwork certain fees in order to do that. They introduced this recently

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Agreed! But there is a legal way to Opt out from the Upwork which ask for Opt out fee. https://www.upwork.com/legal/ (Service section 7).

Comment: I was banned (albeit temporarily, until they actually read messages) just for mentioning bitcoin as an alternative to paypal when reimbursing me for expenses. Information only - so a client could avoid paypal fees... Now I only use email, outside upworks messaging system. I do not consider upworks TOS legitimate after this ban (a bot scanning for keywords). I would have no qualms about offering a reduced price to someone if they buy my time outside upwork. It is ethical.

Comment: https://outsource.com requires you to pay 19$/month for just applying to jobs.

Comment: https://github.com/engineerapart/TheRemoteFreelancer has a longer list of alternative sites

Answer (score 1):

[Here they are mentioning their price:](https://www.upwork.com/blog/2016/05/upwork-pricing/)

> Beginning in June, freelancers will see a sliding service fee of either 5%, 10% or 20%. The service fee is based on a freelancer’s lifetime billings with each client (across all hourly and fixed-price contracts the freelancer has ever had with that client on Upwork).
>
> You’ll pay:
>
> - 20% for the first $500 you bill your client across all contracts
> - 10% for total billings with your client between $500.01 and $10,000
> - 5% for total billings with your client that exceed $10,000

Well, you're only highlighting 20% and not 5%.

Answer (score 0):

I have created today an account on [HubStaff Talent](https://talent.hubstaff.com/). They claim not to have any fees at all. I have not tested it yet to see whether it is true.

So far, I have used Freelancer and UpWork. Both of them have fees. Freelancer even charges you 4 USD for accepting a won project (crazy idea, I guess).

Beside OutSource ( https://www.outsource.com/ ), they have also recently created OutSourceLY ( https://www.outsourcely.com/ ). This one also claims not to have any fees. I guess that they obtain their revenues from the advertisements that they post alongside the useful pieces of information.

The bad thing about OutSourceLY is that one needs to verify their account. So, if you do not feel like contacting ANY of your former employers in order to get some credentials, it is pretty useless.

Comment: There is no way under any circumstance a freelancer website doesn't charge anything. They need to make money.