# Escrow System Alternatives or a Smart Contract For Working Secure

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, safety

For reference is someone don't know what is an escrow system:

> Escrow is a financial instrument whereby an asset or escrow money is
> held by a third party on behalf of two other parties that are in the
> process of completing a transaction.

Working as a freelance I have to deal with people dodging my payment. I have experience been using escrow system from websites like localbitcoins or localcryptos, is pretty good and feel secure.

A client recommend me with [Upwork escrow system](https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/211068208-Escrow-for-Fixed-Price-Jobs) but I know [here](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4759/upwork-taking-20-of-my-money-alternatives?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C50.1366) in freelancing that upwork comission is too much.

Is there another way? online alternatives. Like a smart a contract of some blockchain project especially create for freelancers (ethereum have a project about smart contract) or website that could help with the minimum fee and the best support?

Comment: It sounds like you've had a fantastic idea for a product that no-one is going to sell you. How would someone create an escrow service with minimal fees *and* superior support without making a loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out more than 5 popular escrow system maybe I will need update this list in the future some great projects ([like openbazaar](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2cy45l/can_someone_please_explain_to_me_how_the/cjk7r5h?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)) had to close/pause. But lets start with [upwork direct contract escrow system for non upwork user](https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025040794-Direct-Contracts-with-Clients#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20cost%20for%20me,fee%2C%20only%20the%203.4%25.) and the fee.

Upwork:

> Upwork Escrow protects Client’s deposit until the work is approved.
>
> processing fee of 3.4%
>
> period of 14 days

PayPal:

> PayPal doesn't offer escrow service, but they offer 100% buyer protection. If you don't hear from your seller, PayPal will refund your money.
>
> processing fee of USD 0.30$ plus 5.4% fee
>
> period of 14 days

kiwikiwifly:

> kiwikiwifly escrow service, this is for international buyers and seller.very famous in Australia and New Zealand.
>
> service fees around 1%-1.5%
>
> The waiting time can range from a couple of hours to days

Ethereum:

> Ethereum smart contract, each computer
> has the same digital contract program.And
> they all have the same data, every one
> can check the source codes of the
> “ digital contract program “.
>
> processing fee average 2.822$
>
> period of 14 days

Escrow.com:

> Escrow.com is a privately held internet escrow company acquired in April 2015 by Freelancer Technology Pty Limited.
>
> minimum fee 10$ ([calculator](https://www.escrow.com/fee-calculator))
>
> period of 30 days

Bitcoin:

> Using Multi-signature (multisig) refers to requiring multiple keys to authorize a Bitcoin transaction, rather than a single signature from one key. It has a number of applications. Dividing up responsibility for possession of bitcoins among multiple people..
>
> average bitcoin transaction fee is $23
>
> period: until each private key (person) are agree with terms.

example of third part escrow system using bitcoin:
[image: example of third part escrow system]

I am really sick of scammers working outside popular freelancer platforms (saturated, with hampering my work and dealing with fee so thats why I have to do and I will do more research about this systems.

Edit: This answer is open for more information about escrow system for freelancers.